# Facebook Fan Page - Invite Fans to Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

is there a way to invite fans from a fanpage to an event? (Who are not your friends on facebook)

I browsed the web, but just found answeres, who are some years old.

I already tried to invite with email addresses, but the user doesn't receive this mail. Is there maybe a workaround? With the Facebook Graph? Is there a way to pay facebook, to activate the feature to this account?

Hope somebody can help me,

Thanks in advance,

csskevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not, that would be spammy. You can post the event on the wall of your Facebook Page though, that would be the correct way.